# Close actual Window and open a new Window from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In the first window of my App there is a button to open a second window and in the second window there is also a button to open a third window. All Button-Commands are implemented in my ViewModel.
The current window must be closed before a new window is opened.
To go from the first to the second window, I used the following code:

```
void OpenSecondWindowExecute()
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
    SecondWindow sw = new SecondWindow();
    sw.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
    sw.Show();
}

bool CanOpenSecondWindowExecute()
{
    return true;
}

public ICommand OpenSecondWindow { get { return new RelayCommand(OpenSecondWindowExecute, CanOpenSecondWindowExecute); } }
```

and it works fine because first window represents the MainWindow.

**Problem:**
How can I realize this with the other windows?

Comment: Should not use UI specific logic in ViewModel. Put these code in Click events. Putting in ViewModel will defeat the purpose of viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
   void OpenSecondWindowExecute()
    {
        this.Close();
        SecondWindow sw = new SecondWindow();
        sw.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        sw.Show();
    }
```